# Have drop down list for column show one value but input another

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, data-validation

What I’m looking to do is have a column in sheet A where each cell has a drop down list. The values of that drop down list are in column 1 on sheet B, but when you select a value, it actually inputs the values of column 2 in sheet B

How do I do this

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: one way is by putting a formula in column B that takes column A and transforms it to the value you want.

Comment: @gns100 that’s a good idea, thank you

Comment: I want to make sure that you’re operating on the correct understanding of the Excel model.  *Formulas* do not “send” values to other cells, rather they are the instructions to the current cell how to derive its own value by following your formula.  So as gns100 said, the logic here will be a formula on sheet B that says `if the status of the drop down in A1 = “x”, then fetch the value in B2 of sheet one.`  Procedural languages including VBA can act on a cell and “impose” a value on it.  But a formula in Excel is an instruction to *that cell* on how to determine its own value.  Hope that helps!